# How can i set custom account to pallet balances?

Tags: substrate

I used

- [substrate-node-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template)
- [substrate-front-end-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-front-end-template)

Pallet balance have default accounts.
I had create and edit a chainspec json file

```
      "palletBalances": {
        "balances": [
          [
            "5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY", //Alice
            1152921504606846976
          ],
          [
            "5Fem9dGJe9a6CxuGdFmpuNusGJ1GJ5CvYG78fnjngAbwY3D6",//Custom
            1152921504606846976
          ],
          [
            "5EZX3rWueuPSVag6TT34G1mJmJLQZcVNiSqxSdjSoMnYoFkG",//Custom
            1152921504606846976
          ]
        ]
      },
      "palletSudo": {
        "key": "5Ffm9dHJe9a6CxuGdFmpuNusGJ1GJ5CvYG78fnjngAbwY3D6"
      }
```

When i run substrate-front-end-template
i can't see my accounts

- `5Fem9dGJe9a6CxuGsFmpuNusGJ1GJ8CvYG78fnjngAbwY3D6`
- `5EZX3rWueuPSVag6Tt34G1mJmJLqZcVNiSqxSdjSoMnYoFkG`

How added custom accounts in pallet balance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure you have the keys in your keyring. [here is where they are loaded](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-front-end-template/blob/05f76f34ab60043c329fc24f61790e457a883667/src/substrate-lib/SubstrateContext.js#L84-L113) - the easiest way to manage these is via the https://polkadot.js.org/extension/ and I would highly recommend using that. Then the accounts will appear on the frontend template. You should see the endowed accounts in the chain state, if you query for it. [Here is an example](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/examples/promise/read-storage)